# compiler not executing a particular section

Tags: c#

```
if (radioButton1.Checked)
{
    int a;
    string s = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

    if (s == "30 Days")
    {
        a = 30;
    }                
    if (s == "60 days")
    {
        a = 60;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
    }
    view_n_cstmr v = new view_n_cstmr(a);
    v.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
    v.Show();
}
```

the value of 'a'(int) is not affecting with this code but in swe found that item of combo box
please help me out

Comment: "but in swe found that item of combo box".. say what?

Comment: Use the debugger and breakpoints to find out what's going on.

Comment: I edited your code layout but I really cannot understand/improve your question.

Comment: Can you please explain some further? I can't understand your question..

Comment: Which section exactly does your compiler not execute?

Comment: I'm guessing the `MessageBox.Show` part isn't executing, because of the error in the OPs if-statement flow... however, that has nothing to do with the compiler of course. =)

Comment: `"30 Days"` `"60 days"` in string comparison cases are matter (talking about `D` and `d`).

Comment: What's going on with the rampant downvotes/upvotes of question as well as answers? Explanations?

Comment: First of all, compiler doesnt execute the code but compiles it. I believe your code has zero compilation errors but on execution you are not able to set value of variable 'a'. Is my assumption correct?

Answer (score 3):

The biggest problem in your code (which is probably confusing you) is that the first `if` statement is not "connected" to the next `if...else` statement. Try changing it to:

```
if {...}
else if {...}
else {...}
```

Comment: +1 for actually **explaining** the mistake.

Comment: I believe that message box is just to show if selection is other than 30 and 60 days.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is problem of string sensetive comparision.

Try following code for string insensetive comparision -

```
if (radioButton1.Checked)
{
    int a; string s = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

    if (string.Compare(s, "30 days", true) == 0) { a = 30; } 
    else if (string.Compare(s, "60 days", true) == 0) { a = 60; } 
    else 
    { 
        MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()); 
    }
}
```

Comment: The choices might very well be `30 Days` and `60 days`. And you've failed to fix the if-statement logic flaw.

Comment: @J.Steen - fixed as per your suggestion...

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
if (radioButton1.Checked)
{
    int a = 0;
    string s = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

    if (s == "30 Days")
        a = 30;            
    else if (s == "60 days")
        a = 60;
    else
        MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());

    view_n_cstmr v = new view_n_cstmr(a);
    v.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
    v.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
switch (s.ToLower())
{
    case "30 days":
       a = 30;
       break;
    case "60 days":
       a = 60;
       break;
    default:           
       MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
       break;
}
```

Comment: Take care of "Days" and "days" :)

Answer (score 0):

As many have pointed out the if else statements that you are using are not connected.
And also. In your combobox, do you have any more items then `"30 Days"` and `"60 days"`?
In your else you are not setting the integer a.

This will cause the compliation error : "`Use of unassigned local variable 'a'`"

This row in your code.

```
view_n_cstmr v = new view_n_cstmr(a);
```

Perhaps assign the variable 'a' with a default value, or return in the else statement?